# JavaScript filter by two parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
const dates = [
{arrival_date:'2019-01-01',departure_date:'2019-01-07'},
{arrival_date:'2019-01-07',departure_date:'2019-01-09'},
{arrival_date:'2019-01-10',departure_date:'2019-01-20'}
];

let is_filter_by_arrival_date = true;
let is_filter_by_dept_date = true;
```

I have an array called `dates`.
Also I have two Boolean variables `is_filter_by_arrival_date` and `is_filter_by_dept_date`.

Also I have another four variables.

```js
let arrival_from = '';
let arrival_to = '';

let dept_from = '';
let dept_to = '';
```

What I want is if the Boolean variable `is_filter_by_arrival_date` is `true`. I need to filter my **dates** using **arrival_from** and **arrival_to** same as for the **is_filter_by_dept_date**.

What I have done up-to now is

```
let results = dates.filter(e => {if(is_filter_by_arrival_date){
    e.arrival_date <= arrival_to && e.arrival_date >= arrival_to
}})
```

But I want to filter not only by the `is_filter_by_arrival_date`. I want both `is_filter_by_arrival_date` and `is_filter_by_dept_date`.

How do I achieve this using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really understand what do you want to achieve, however, I want to note:

1. Within the callback function you can check the condition of your values.
2. Return the values. At the moment you are not returning anything, and probably you are have an array with `undefined` values

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator like below for cleaner code

```
let results = dates.filter(e => {
  return (
    is_filter_by_arrival_date ? 
    // verify your condition for arrival date
    e.arrival_date <= arrival_to && e.arrival_date >= arrival_to 
    : 
    true
  ) && (
    is_filter_by_dept_date ? 
    // verify your condition for dept date
    : 
    true
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let results = dates.filter(e => {
  if(is_filter_by_arrival_date && is_filter_by_dept_date){
    return ( e.arrival_date <= arrival_to && e.arrival_date >= arrival_from &&
             e.departure_date <= dept_to && e.departure_date > = dept_from);
  }
  else if(is_filter_by_arrival_date){
    return e.arrival_date <= arrival_to && e.arrival_date >= arrival_from
  } else if(is_filter_by_dept_date) {
    return e.departure_date <= dept_to && e.departure_date > = dept_from
  }
  return true;
})
```

I think in your question you have just used arrival_to you should also make use of arrival_from. I have implemented according to my understanding.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the other filter as well? Also `e.arrival_date <= arrival_to && e.arrival_date >= arrival_to` is the same as `e.arrival_date === arrival_to`, since only that exact date can match. A date can never be both > and < than another date at the same time. So somthing like this might work:

```js
const dates = [
  {arrival_date:'2019-01-01',departure_date:'2019-01-07'},
  {arrival_date:'2019-01-07',departure_date:'2019-01-09'},
  {arrival_date:'2019-01-10',departure_date:'2019-01-20'}
];

let is_filter_by_arrival_date = true;
let is_filter_by_dept_date = true;

let arrival_from = null;
let arrival_to = '2019-01-01';

let dept_from = null;
let dept_to = '2019-01-07';

let results = dates.filter( timeslot => {
  if ( is_filter_by_arrival_date && is_filter_by_dept_date ) {
    return timeslot.arrival_date === arrival_to && timeslot.departure_date === dept_to;
  }
  else if ( is_filter_by_arrival_date ) {
    return timeslot.arrival_date === arrival_to; 
  }
  else if ( is_filter_by_dept_date ) {
    return timeslot.departure_date === dept_to;
  }
  else throw new Error( 'no valid filters selected' );
});

console.log( results );
```

But I think you might have an error in your logic. If the idea is that the user can select a range of arrival and departure dates, hence else would you have both arrival_from and arrival_to, then you need to actually compare `e.arrival_date <= arrival_to && e.arrival_date >= arrival_from` instead of comparing to arrival_to both times. If this is true, then the code becomes:

```js
const dates = [
  {arrival_date:'2019-01-01',departure_date:'2019-01-07'},
  {arrival_date:'2019-01-07',departure_date:'2019-01-09'},
  {arrival_date:'2019-01-10',departure_date:'2019-01-20'}
];

let is_filter_by_arrival_date = true;
let is_filter_by_dept_date = true;

let arrival_from = '2018-12-30';
let arrival_to = '2019-01-03';

let dept_from = '2019-01-07';
let dept_to = '2019-01-15';

let results = dates.filter( timeslot => {
  if ( is_filter_by_arrival_date && is_filter_by_dept_date ) {
    return timeslot.arrival_date >= arrival_from && timeslot.arrival_date <= arrival_to && timeslot.departure_date >= dept_from && timeslot.departure_date <= dept_to;
  }
  else if ( is_filter_by_arrival_date ) {
    return timeslot.arrival_date >= arrival_from && timeslot.arrival_date <= arrival_to
  }
  else if ( is_filter_by_dept_date ) {
    return timeslot.departure_date >= dept_from && timeslot.departure_date <= dept_to
  }
  else throw new Error( 'no valid filters selected' );
});

console.log( results );
```

The filter can be written shorter with ternaries and such as the other solutions show. But I preferred writing it out fully with if/else statements to make it more clear how the filter works.

Comment: Hence the last sentence: "The filter can be written shorter with ternaries and such as the other solutions show. But I preferred writing it out fully with if/else statements to make it more clear how the filter works." I would use array.each over an all conditions array if a 3rd (and so on ) one would be added.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some boolean algebra. `bypass || condition` will evaluate to true if `bypass` is set, otherwise whatever `condition` is:

```
 const result = dates.filter(({ arrivalDate, departureDate }) => {

    const arrivalFits = arrivalDate <= arrivalTo && arrivalDate >= arrivalTo;
    const departureFits = departureDate <= departureTo && departureDate >= departureTo;

   return (!filterByArrival || arrivalFits) && (!filterByDeparture || departureFits);
});
```